Is my assumption about "Enabling FM+ I2C on lower frequency gives more robustness" correct?
There have been like hundreds of topics and questions on how to get long cable lengths with I2C since it's the only "controlled" communication, and unlike CAN, is available even on cheapest Microcontrollers. However no one found the courage to say that it can go longer than normal PCB traces since it is bound to somehow strict bus capacitance and standards. The well-known I2C line buffers are quite expensive and sometimes 10x the price of a microcontroller.
However, I recently stumbled upon the characteristics of FM+:

The acceptable bus capacitance is increased by 150 pf (550pf from 400pf), not a very big difference but quite useful
The drive strength of I/O pins in FM+ is increased ~10 times, from up to 3mA, to over 20mA (I just used the expression from microchip AVR datasheet for new AVRxx microcontrollers):


A frequency of 100 kHz can be used for the SMBus environment. For the
Standard mode (Sm) and Fast mode (Fm), the operating frequency has
slew rate limited output, while for the Fast mode Plus (Fm+), it has
x10 output drive strength.


According to NXP themselves, we can somehow enable FM+ (hardware capability) and use lower frequency since the SCL clock is usually defined by user.


The drivers in Fast-mode Plus parts are strong enough to satisfy the
Fast-mode Plus timing specification with the same 400 pF load as
Standard-mode parts. To be backward compatible with Standard-mode,
they are also tolerant of the 1 μs rise time of Standard- mode parts.
In applications where only Fast-mode Plus parts are present, the high
drive strength and tolerance for slow rise and fall times allow the
use of larger bus capacitance as long as set-up, minimum LOW time and
minimum HIGH time for Fast-mode Plus are all satisfied and the fall
time and rise time do not exceed the 300 ns (tf) and 1 μs (tr)
specifications of Standard-mode. Bus speed can be traded against
load capacitance to increase the maximum capacitance by about a factor
of ten.

So basically we can get higher cable length and less-deteriorated signal, just by using FM+ capable microcontrollers and chips, and enabling FM+ and still using low baudrates like 100KHz or 200KHz.
Is this assumption correct?

No, you are not necessarily correct.
If you need to communicate over a longer bus with more capacitance and stronger pull-ups, you need the devices at both ends of the bus to be able to drive that bus.
And for e.g. generic microcontrollers, they need extra drive capability support, and in STM32 MCUs this must be enabled on the GPIO pin, and not all GPIO pins where you can route the I2C are FM+ compatible. For the GPIO, it just a matter of disabling other pin strength and slew rate settings to use even faster and stronger setting, to be able to reach 20mA drive while pulling down to 0.4V.
But the problem of stronger output drive comes at a cost - the faster falling edge can be too fast and it causes undershoots and ringing, because your IO pin output impedance is poorly matched with the cable.
So while my experience of actually using FM+ mode at FM+ speeds is almost zero (I know that on some MCUs there are pins and such chips selected where FM+ could be used but to keep all buses identical only FM was used), if you simply think of the concept of driving long cables with strong GPIO pins directly, it will be a nightmare. You might need series damping resistors to combat the reflections, which means slower fall times, which means you might not be able to be within FM+ specs any more and you need to basically slow down the bus, as you need 120ns max fall time both at the bus and at the IO pin, which limits the use of series resistors.
On the other hand, the allowed tricks to handle above the rated bus capacitance are listed in the I2C specs you quote. This includes higher output drive for allowing stronger pull-ups. This is what enabling the MCU for FM+ mode simply does. Another thing included in the list is to reduce the clock speed, so that the high and low portions of the clock are long enough if rise and fall times are longer due to high capacitance or low MCU drive ability and weaker pull-ups. The problem is that all the chips need to be verified to handle longer rise/fall times, and many do.
So, this means that while latest SMBUS standard has adopted the FM+ mode, the early SMBUS chips were only up to 100 kHz and limited to 4mA drive. If you have such a chip on bus, it limits your pull-up to a weaker one, and thus that defines the pull-up resitor value and the total bus capacitance defines the rise time which defines the speed you can communicate. The fact that you have a super-strong 20mA drive on your MCU is irrelevant, and the strong drive may cause signal integrity issues as it outputs faster edges.
As an another example, the 400 kHz FM is also limited to 400pF, but if you have standard 3mA chips on the bus, you cannot reach 400kHz as 3mA drive limits the pull-ups. If all chips are capable of 6mA pull-ups, then it's possible, but may require active pull-ups instead of simple resistors to reach it.
Then there are buses that work fine because they are specified to do so - for example I2C-based DDC. In some scenarios they are required to work with 800pF of capacitance, at 2.5mA drive, so well outside of I2C specs but it's only a 100 kHz bus.

This assumption is correct. FM+ is an extension to standard I2C, so it is still backward compatible, but can run with longer cables EXOR higher speed.

This is true but does not mean more robustness, as the stronger drive strength required means faster fall times, which means more bandwidth required, which means more ringing and undershoots, more bandwidth required from transmission line, etc. So sometimes you get a more robust bus by not driving it faster than you need. So it could make problems worse by setting IO stages to FM+ edge rates while using it at slower clock speed.
